# How to combine and rename properties of arrays in powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, arraylist

I am pulling data from an API that ConnectWise offers. I am trying to pull a list of usernames and password and put them in to a format which I can either reference in another script (or combiner with this one), or that I can export to a CSV. I'd prefer the first if possible.

The code:

```
Function Get-CWConfiguration
{
[string]$BaseUri     = "$CWServerRoot"
[string]$Accept      = "application/vnd.connectwise.com+json; version=v2015_3"
[string]$ContentType = "application/json"
[string]$Authstring  = $CWInfo + '+' + $CWCredentials1 + ':' + $CWCredentials2 
$encodedAuth         = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(($Authstring)));

$Headers=@{"Authorization"="Basic $encodedAuth"}
Invoke-RestMethod -URI $BaseURI -Headers $Headers -ContentType $ContentType -Method Get
}

$username = (Get-CWConfiguration).questions | Where-Object {($_.questionid -eq 419)} | Sort-Object -Property questionid | select answer
$password = (Get-CWConfiguration).questions | Where-Object {($_.questionid -eq 420)} | Sort-Object -Property questionid | select answer
```

Everything above the `$username` variable is the stuff connecting to the API and I did not modify that. The code below is the best way I found to pull the info that I need. This is returning each variable as an array, which is fine but if that happens I need to have an array with 2 columns. 1 named Username and the other named Password. if I do a `$username | Get-Member` it returns:

```
Name        MemberType   Definition                         
----        ----------   ----------                         
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)     
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                  
GetType     Method       type GetType()                     
ToString    Method       string ToString()                  
answer      NoteProperty string answer=admin@admin.com
```

My end goal is to have a variable like `$credentials` output something that displays like:

```
Username             Password
--------            ----------                         
admin1@admin.com      Password1
admin2@admin.com      Password2
admin3@admin.com      Password3
```

Most methods I have tried have resulted in everything put output to 1 line or 1 column. I'm not sure if I should be combining the arrays and renaming the `$username.answer` and `$password.answer` fields or creating a `PSObject`? My main difficulty has been that both variables have that same `answer` `NoteProperty`

Comment: In my experience, everything outputting to one line or one column is because you're dealing expressly with strings. YOu're going to want to create a new CustomPSObject and assign it two properties, one being $Username.Answer and the other being $Password.Answer as you indicated. Or Set that property, selected and expanded, equal to another variable and then do some string manipulation on it to make it look proper.

Comment: Ok yeah CustomPSObject seems like the way to go. I haevn't done string manipulation yet, I'm new to powershell. Deeper down this rabbit hole I dive! Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to create new objects with the expanded properties of the current objects. This could all look something like this (note that I'm manually creating analogs for what you're all dealing with and ignoring the string manipulation you'll likely have to do)

```
$Username = New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject -Property @{Answer = "Answer:Hithisispatrick"}
$Password = New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject -Property @{Answer = "Answer:HelloThisisSquidward"}

$UsernameAnswer = $Username | Select -ExpandProperty Answer
$PasswordAnswer = $Password | Select -ExpandProperty Answer


$Final = New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject -Property @{UserName= $UsernameAnswer ; Password = $PAsswordAnswer}
```

This should give you output something like this:

```
UserName               Password
--------               --------
Answer:Hithisispatrick Answer:HelloThisisSquidward
```

Then if you want to parameterize it/Expand it, you should be able then to toss it in to a foreach loop and have it output the Custom Object, setting that equal to an array that then builds out of those objects, like so(I'll use while to make it simpler to show):

```
$Count = 0
$Username = New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject -Property @{Answer = "Answer:Hithisispatrick"}
$Password = New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject -Property @{Answer = "Answer:HelloThisisSquidward"}
$Array = While ($Count -lt 5){
$UsernameAnswer = $Username | Select -ExpandProperty Answer
$PAsswordAnswer = $Password | Select -ExpandProperty Answer

$Final = New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject -Property @{UserName= $UsernameAnswer ; Password = $PAsswordAnswer}
$Final
$Count += 1
}


$Array
```

This produces something like this:

```
Password                    UserName
--------                    --------
Answer:HelloThisisSquidward Answer:Hithisispatrick
Answer:HelloThisisSquidward Answer:Hithisispatrick
Answer:HelloThisisSquidward Answer:Hithisispatrick
Answer:HelloThisisSquidward Answer:Hithisispatrick
Answer:HelloThisisSquidward Answer:Hithisispatrick
```

Comment: The first section of code you gave me did the trick for the correct formatting of columns but all the data is on one line in each column. Also, I know you said you used a while to make it simpler but I think I might not be understanding how to translate that to a foreach. Sorry, I'm very new to PS and still learning a ton. I really appreciate your response!

Comment: No problem, I could totally understand the confusion! I think I may have misunderstood a bit, you may not need the loop depending on how this call is functioning.. ANd I'm sorry, I don't believe I understand what you mean with all the data being on one line in each column. Is that currently returning multiple Usernames and Passwords, all in that first column? If so, you'll have to break that string apart. Store it in to a variable and then use the -Split operator to split it in to sections  based on some kind of delimiter. I may be able to help, if you have an obfuscated result to provide